# AzureAD Token Validation

Tags: c#, .net, azure-active-directory, jwt

I'm trying to validate a token that was provided by Azure AD inside of an AWS Lambda Function. At the moment I have a MVC Website that you can authenticate to Azure AD with, which returns a JWT Token. This JWT will be passed up to an AWS API Gateway where a Lambda Authorizer will verify it.

At first I thought the correct method was to pass the JWT back to Azure AD to verify the token. However after reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validating-tokens), it appears I need to decrypt the token, and validate the issuer and audience. This lead me to [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-validate-azure-ad-token-using-console-application/), which does successfully validate the token. However, if i change `mySecret` to not match the one configured in Azure AD, it still successfully validates?

```
        var authToken = "JWTToken";
        string key = "I thought this needed to be the client secret in Azure AD but any string will still pass verification";

        string myTenant = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
        var myAudience = "api://xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
        var myIssuer = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "https://sts.windows.net/{0}/", myTenant);
        var mySecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key));
        var stsDiscoveryEndpoint = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/.well-known/openid-configuration", myTenant);
        var configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsDiscoveryEndpoint, new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
        var config = await configManager.GetConfigurationAsync();

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidAudience = myAudience,
            ValidIssuer = myIssuer,
            IssuerSigningKeys = config.SigningKeys,
            ValidateLifetime = false,
            IssuerSigningKey = mySecurityKey,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
        };

        var validatedToken = (SecurityToken)new JwtSecurityToken();

        // Throws an Exception as the token is invalid (expired, invalid-formatted, etc.)  
        tokenHandler.ValidateToken(authToken, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
```

I have Azure AD configured to [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-1-MyOrg/Client), where the Client is the MVC website and the Service is the Lambda Auhorizer. TLDR: This is basically two client registrations, where the Lambda Authoizer has an exposed API and the MVC website has a client secret.

Have a taken the right approach? If so, how do I fix the issue i am facing?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used something like this:

```cs
string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your-tenant-id>/";
string clientId = "<your-client-id>";

IConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configurationManager =
    new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>($"{authority}.well-known/openid-configuration", new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
OpenIdConnectConfiguration openIdConfig = await configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken.None);

var validationParams = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidAudience = clientId,
    IssuerSigningKeys = openIdConfig.SigningKeys
};
```

It uses the authority to download the valid issuer, signing keys etc.

Comment: How is that secured? Since the authority and client id are not private, couldn't a malicious user create a valid token using them?

Comment: The only way to create a valid token is if you have Azure AD's private key. Authority and client ID are public. Should maybe clarify that the signing keys downloaded are only the _public keys_. They can be used to verify tokens, but not create them.

Comment: OK that makes sense. Thanks for your help! This is slightly off topic but I wonder if you know why when protecting API's (Like in the third link), a private key is stored on the API which would mean it doesn't use this same method?

Comment: I think that's a client secret/certificate that is used to _acquire_ tokens, not validate them.